# ReactJS passing input data to next screen/component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I've looked up whole google for my answer (haha).
What I am trying to achieve:

My fist screen is a form with some input fields which store the input to state.
By clicking "submit" the user comes to the next page/screen, where the previous input is supposed to show up. I want to show only the input data as a p-tag, not as an input tag anymore.

How do I achieve this? I am bloody new to reactjs.

I've thought about multiple solutions:

1. store the input data to an external JSON (which seems pretty complicated)
2. pass the data as props, but I am not aware of how I would do this

Thanks so far!

Comment: Is the next 'screen' a brand new page that gets loaded? Or is it all part of a single-page thing and React controls when to shoe the 'next screen'?

Comment: Does your second screen share the same parent component as the first screen?

Comment: I made a very crude example for you in my post: https://jsfiddle.net/df4s9ey8/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your second screen has the same parent component as your first, something like this:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.state.showFirstScreen && <FirstScreen />}
            {this.state.showSecondcreen && <Secondcreen />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

If that's the case, your `FirstScreen` component can accept a prop called something like `onSubmit` -- you say that you already store the input values from `FirstScreen` in state, so when `FirstScreen` is finished, you can call `this.props.onSubmit(this.state)` and it will send up the state to your parent component, as long as you've defined a callback function in the parent component:

```
{this.state.showFirstScreen && <FirstScreen onSubmit={this.onFirstScreenSubmit} />}
```

Then, you can save the state of the first screen into the state of your Parent component, and pass that part of the state down to `SecondScreen`

[edit] here's a very crude example: https://jsfiddle.net/df4s9ey8/

Comment: Thank you so far for your help! I understand the way you are solving the problem. But unfortunately the both components do not have the same parent component. The switch of the screens works through routers. Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: You can use a global state handler like Redux, React Context, or if you're really cheeky and want to throw caution to the wind, simply do `window._state_of_screen_1 = {myObj}` inside Screen 1, and then when you get to Screen 2 you can read `window._state_of_screen_1` and do what you want with it

Comment: Alternatively, you can also figure out how to pass state up through props within the context of using Routers. That's also possible

Comment: https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-components/

Comment: Thanks again! I found a solution for the problem. I Used routers as you suggested. Thank you so much!